# Can Maven read a pom from another source than a file, and how?

Tags: maven

I would like to let a script create a pom on-the-fly, but not write it to the file system, but pipe it to Maven. Something like
`echo '<project ...><groupId>mygroup</groupId><artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId><version>1.0.0</version> ... <dependencies><dependency>... </project>' | mvn dependency:tree`

This doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve such behaviour?
We are using Maven 3.5.0.

Comment: First question: Why would you like to do that? Furthermore that's not possible...

Comment: I don't have a specific problem to solve. It's just that I am curious.
Poms are to some extent dynamic by use of properties. E.g. the version of a dependency needs not be fixed at the time of writing a pom file, but can be set by a property, which is passed at runtime.   
This doesn't help e.g. to add additional dependencies at runtime.
To do so a pom file has to be written dynamically by some script or so and then passed to a Maven call.  
The intermediate step with a pom file is annoying, hence my question.

Comment: The use of properties to create a kind of dynamics is not the right way. By runtime you mean the build time of the appropriate project. If you simply write it to the filesystem then you can call maven...